# Environment hiding its content

Tags: environments

In the following code, I would like to build an environment that just hides its content, this content can use any standard LaTeX code like enumerated lists, tables...

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\newenvironment{forshort}{}{}


\begin{document}

Something in the whole course.


\begin{forshort}
    Just a summary...
\end{forshort}

\end{document}
```

Is there a ready-to-use package ?

I have tried `tagging` but this is only for "textual" contents : this not seems to work with the `enumerate` environment.

The package `scontents` could be hacked but the problem I've met is that I can't define an environment using `\begin{scontents}[store-env = donotshow] ... \end{scontents}`.

Comment: Much more simple : 1) load the package `version`
2) define `forshort` with `\newenvironment{forshort}{\relax}{\relax}` 3) add in preamble `\excludeversion{forshort}`

Comment: There are censor packages, couldn't you use those? https://www.ctan.org/pkg/censor

Comment: Version 1.8 of `scontents` has built-in `\newenvsc` command that covers this specific case, you can use `\newenvsc{forshort}[store-env=forshort,print-env=false]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this new feature !

Comment: @projetmbc you're welcome :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latest version (1.8) of [scontents](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/scontents) has built-in `\newenvsc` command that covers this specific case:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: clean: { extensions: [ aux, log] }
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{scontents}
\newenvsc{forshort}[store-env=forshort,print-env=false]
\begin{document}

Something in the whole course.

\begin{forshort}
    Just a summary...
\end{forshort}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

There is a package for this:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{comment}
%\includecomment{forshort}
\excludecomment{forshort}



\begin{document}

Something in the whole course.


\begin{forshort}
    Just a summary...
\end{forshort}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Good done ! Thanks. Such a shame ! I was looking forward harder things to do.