# New Command for Comment?

Tags: environments, comments

> **Question:** Is there an environment similar to the comment environment that suppresses text and space but can be called using inline commands?

I'm trying to develop a better way to type my solutions into my homework sets. Ideally, I'd like to have something in the preamble that I comment/uncomment to include/exclude solutions. I have a MWE below to demonstrate the type of thing I'm trying to implement, but of course, in it's current form, it doesn't work.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\newenvironment{solution}{}{}

\newcommand{\soln}{\begin{solution}}
\newcommand{\solnend}{\end{solution}}

\newcommand{\nosolutions}{
    \renewcommand{\soln}{\begin{comment}}
    \renewcommand{\solnend}{\end{comment}}
}

%\nosolutions

\begin{document}
    What is a question?

    \soln
        Not an answer.
    \solnend
\end{document}
```

I know of one way to partially succeed in what I'm trying to do, and that is to define the new command with an optional argument. The issue I have with this is that when I have a problem with multiple parts that is quite long, it may take a non-trivial amount of time to actually locate the relevant part of the code (for reference, I'm using WinEdt paired with Sumatra, so I can double click the pdf in Sumatra and it takes me to that part of the code; with an optional argument, though, I'm always taken to the very end). A MWE demonstrating this method is below.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\newenvironment{solution}{}{}

\newcommand{\soln}[1]{\begin{solution}#1\end{solution}}

\newcommand{\nosolutions}{
    \renewcommand{\soln}[1]{}
}

\nosolutions

\begin{document}
    What is a question?

    \soln{
        Not an answer.
    }
\end{document}
```

> The ending question: is there anything like the comment environment available that suppresses text and space?

Comment: Can you say what exactly is wrong with using `\includecomment{solution}` (or `\excludecomment{solution}`) and just using `\begin{solution}` and `\end{solution}` everywhere? (Why is it that you insist on "inline commands" instead of "environments"?)

Comment: @WillieWong: I'm not sure I understand the question exactly. I did try using `\excludecomment{solution}` in one of my attempts, but I couldn't get the file to compile. To answer the second question: there is no particular reason, it was just simply my goal.

Comment: did you load the `comment` package?

Comment: @WillieWong: Indeed. :)

Comment: It generally helps if you can show exactly the compilation error, and the minimum non-working example, instead of just saying that the file won't compile.

Comment: Also: maybe instead of reinventing the wheel, you should look at the [exam class](https://ctan.org/pkg/exam) which can be pretty easily used to typeset homework sets with optionally included answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Commenting out large sections](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17816/5764)

Comment: @Werner: I came across that question, but I don't feel like this is a duplicate since the answers there are already mentioned here. The methods don't work because the `comment` environment is looking for `\end{comment}` which I don't provide.

Comment: @WillieWong: Thanks; I'll take a look at the exam class and see if it can do what I'm seeking.

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/509595/7832

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the package `scontents` is adapted to this job, if I understood your question and the example file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scontents}
\newenvsc{solution}[store-env=solution,print-env=false]
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\section{Only questions}
What is a question?

\begin{solution}
  Not an answer.
\end{solution}

What is the next question?

\begin{solution}
  An answer.
\end{solution}

\section{Questions with answer}
Other question?

\begin{solution}[print-env=true]
  Other answer.
\end{solution}

\section{Only solutions}
% Print solutions
\getstored[1]{solution}\par
\getstored[2]{solution}

% OK, print last
\getstored[3]{solution}

\section{Use default command}
Really another question?
\Scontents[store-cmd=solution]{Yes, other answer}

% now print
\getstored[4]{solution}
\end{document}
```

[image: print-en=false]

If we switch to `print-env=true`

[image: print=env=true]

The truth is you can play with the package options, using the command `\setupsc` or with the local options `[print-env=<true|false>]` and `[print-cmd=<true|false>]`, the current version does not (yet) allow you to create a custom command, only environments, I recommend you read the documentation.
(Credit to @Werner for example)

Comment: Thanks! I think this is exactly what I was asking about. For future readers: Willie Wong's comment on the original post (regarding the exam class) provided me the tools to accomplish what I was going for along with the tools to do many other things. However, as far as answers go, I think this answer most cleanly solves the problem.

Comment: @Clayton: This package was born, among many other ideas, a little to give answer to this type of problematic (the classic files of `question/answer`). The `exam` class is very good, although today I prefer to use `xsim` package, I'm glad my answer is helpful, good luck with your work.

Answer (score 5):

You can define `\soln` to grab everything up to `\solnend` and then either set it (`\showsolutions`) or not (`\nosolutions`).

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\showsolutions}{\long\def\soln##1\solnend{##1}}
\newcommand{\nosolutions}{\long\def\soln##1\solnend{}}

\showsolutions
%\nosolutions

\begin{document}

What is a question?

\soln
  Not an answer.
\solnend

What is the next question?

\soln
  An answer.
\solnend

\end{document}
```

With `\showsolutions`:

[image]

With `\nosolutions`:

[image]

---

To understand the definition of `\soln`, you'll have to understand how `\def` works. `\def` has the following syntax (from p 203 of [The TeX Book](http://www.ctex.org/documents/shredder/src/texbook.pdf)):

> Definitions have the general form
>
> ```
> \def<control sequence><parameter text>{<replacement text>}
> ```
>
> where the `<parameter text>` contains no braces, and where all occurrences of `{` and `}` in the `<replacement text>` are properly nested. Furthermore the `#` symbol has a special significance: In the `<parameter text>`, the first appearance of `#` must be followed by `1`, the next by `2`, and so on; up to nine `#`'s are allowed. In the `<replacement text>` each `#` must be followed by a digit that appeared after `#` in the `<parameter text>`, or else the `#` should be followed by another `#`. The latter case stands for a single `#` token when the macro is expanded; the former case stands for insertion of the corresponding argument.
>
> ...
>
> How does TeX determine where an argument stops, you ask. Answer: There
>   are two cases. A *delimited parameter* is followed in the `<parameter text>`
>   by one or more non-parameter tokens, before reaching the end of the parameter text
>   or the next parameter token; in this case the corresponding argument is the shortest (possibly empty) sequence of tokens with properly nested `{...}` groups that is followed in the input by this particular list of non-parameter tokens. (Category codes and character codes must both match, and control sequence names must be the same.) An *undelimited parameter* is followed immediately in the `<parameter text>` by a parameter token, or it occurs at the very end of the parameter text; in this case the corresponding argument is the next non-blank token, unless that token is '`{`', when the argument will be the entire `{...}` group that follows. In both cases, if the argument found in this way has the form '`{<nested tokens>}`', where `<nested tokens>` stands for any sequence of tokens that is properly nested with respect to braces, the outermost braces enclosing
>   the argument are removed and the `<nested tokens>` will remain.

The definition of `\soln` (under `\showsolutions`) uses a *delimited parameter* in the `<parameter text>`:

```
\def\soln#1\solnend{#1}
```

As such, `\soln` will grab everything following `\soln` up to an *explicit* `\solnend` in the input stream (so, effectively, everything between `\soln` and `\solnend`, and call that `#1`) and set it as-is (the `<replacement text>` is just whatever is grabbed - `#1`). So, you can't use `\soln` without a future `\solnend` in the input stream; they to together.

Under `\nosolutions`, the same happens (a *delimited parameter* in the `<parameter text>`), but whatever captured is never set (no `#1` within the `<replacement text>`).

We use a `\long` `\def`inition, because the argument `#1` - whatever is between `\soln` and `\solnend` - could contain paragraphs of text (otherwise a regular `\def` would suffice).

Also, since the definition of `\soln` is made within another macro (`\showsolutions` and/or `\nosolutions`), doubling of the `#` is necessary (see the answer to Exercise 20.5 on p 329 within [the TeX Book](http://www.ctex.org/documents/shredder/src/texbook.pdf)).

Comment: As a nonexpert in LaTeX, can you explain how this implementation actually works? I see what you've typed and I can usually figure out what each thing is doing, but this answer seems to have details that I'm wholly unfamiliar with.

Comment: @Clayton: I've added some detail about the `\def`inition of `\soln` at the end of the answer.

Answer (score 4):

The following basic example should work

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{comment}

\includecomment{soln} % Change to \excludecomment if you don't want solutions printed

\begin{document}
Q: why does the chicken cross the road.

\begin{soln}
A: To get to the other side
\end{soln}
\end{document}
```

If instead of environments and you want to, absolutely, use macros to turn on and off commenting, there's some [historical code](https://ctan.org/pkg/comment-pln) that you can look at that does the sort of thing you want.

Comment: Does this treat `soln` as an environment? That is, if I want to change the formatting of `soln`, is there a way to do that? Something to clearly distinguish it from the text of the problem?

Comment: If you want to format `soln`, please read Section 3 of the documentation for the `comment` package.

Comment: My apologies, Willie; I've been busy. I'm reading through the documentation for the exam class and think that this will probably be something I want to utilize. I appreciate you bringing it to my attention; if I can get it to work in exactly the way I want, I'll certainly accept this answer. In the interim, I leave an upvote and my a note of my gratitude. :)